# Same function name in javascript (Nested function and outside function )

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function as below. 
My Problem is that I need to print `function b()` inside a function. Here `function a()` is parent function. and I have done it by taking `c= new a()` and `console.log(b())` . I got the right value as I expected. But inside the parent function I have another function named `test()` and with same name there is another function outside the parent function. After printing `function b()` I call the `function test()` . But it return the value from the parent function. I need to get an alert as `needed answer` which is in outer function. Is there any way to get my expected result without changing the function name.? Both functions `test()` are needed.

> Expected result:  `function b()` =  2 and `function test()` = needed answer
>
> Current result :  `function b()` =  2 and `function test()` = 4

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

```js
function a() {
 var val = 1;
 var otherval = 2;
 
        b = function() {
  return val + 1;
        }
 
        test = function() {
           qwerty = otherval + b();
           alert(qwerty);
        } 

   return 'OK';  
 }
 
function test(){
    alert('needed answer');
}
  
c = new a();
console.log(b()); //return 2 
test(); //alert 4 but I needed alert needed answer
```

Comment: When you declare variables without `var`, they become part of global scope. Change it and it will work

Comment: Please correct the code formatting

Answer (score 2):

As Rajesh Pointed out, declaring a function without using `var` will make it a global variable. Use `var` before test function to get expected value. But this will make it inaccessible outside the function `a()`. For that, assign the functions to `this` object and access then as shown below.

```js
function a() {
 var val = 1;
 var otherval = 2;
    this.b = function() {  //prepend this
     return val + 1;
    }
    this.test = function() {  //prepend this
        qwerty = otherval + b();
        alert(qwerty);
    } 
    return 'OK';  
}
 
function test(){
 alert('needed answer');
}
  
c = new a();
console.log(c.b()); //return 2 
test(); //alert 4
```

Comment: First thanks for crediting. Now you have fixed 1 problem, but have left `b`. It should throw error(*which was, in your previous edits*). Second, if the only problem is missing `var`, it makes this as a typographical mistake and it **should** be closed and not answered.

Comment: @Rajesh now it should be fine? in order to make function `b` accessible, it should be assigned to the `a`?

Comment: @Rajesh I would like to see your detailed comments on this as we all are here to learn

Comment: Taking back my vote, still I believe this is a typographical question and should not be answered. Since your fix falls in gray area, not voting. But still  its wrong in my understanding.

Comment: Your `this.test` will fail. See this is why I didn't want anyone to answer. This adds lots of blank areas and makes lot of repeated conversations to fix and we are still not clear on OP's intentions.

Comment: @Rajesh I did vote to close but if eventually it doesn't, I thought of highlighting your comment so that whoever lands to this page should get help. I did wait a while for you to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You need slight modification in your code. Do this and it will work as per your requirement -

```js
function a() {
 var val = 1;
 var otherval = 2;
 
    b = function() {
  return val + 1;
 }
 
    this.test = function() {
  qwerty = otherval + b();
   alert(qwerty);
 } 
   return 'OK';  
}
 
function test(){
 alert('needed answer');
}
  
c = new a();
alert(this.b()); //return 2 
test(); //alert 4
```